# Replace columns less than a threshold to 0

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has 200 columns. I want to use dplyr to clean the data so that every number less than 0.05 is replaced with 0. A sample `df` was pasted below.

```
df
0.07262
0.039885
0.090173
0.124043
0.09201
0.068309
0.146381
0.09127
0.060768
0.111031
```

This is the desired outcome.

```
df
0.07262
0
0.090173
0.124043
0.09201
0.068309
0.146381
0.09127
0.060768
0.111031
```

This is my code: `df2 <- mutate_all(ifelse(<0.05,0.,))` but it doesn't work. Any guidance is welcome.

Comment: You need to use dplyr or is base R enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dplyr:

```
df <- mutate_all(df, funs(ifelse(. < 0.5, 0, .)))
```

base R:

```
df[df < 0.05] <- 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using base R

```
  df[df < 0.05] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can define the function before and then call it in the `mutate_all`

```
smallToZero <- function(x) {if_else(x<.05, 0, x)}
df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate_all(smallToZero)
```

You can also have it as an un-named function using . as:

```
df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(if_else(.<.05, 0, .)))
```